# Windows 7 won't start when external hard drives are connected

Tags: windows-7, windows, external-hard-drive

Whenever I start or restart my computer with my external hard drives connected, Windows won't boot. I have to disconnect them and then reconnect them after windows loads. They are connected via usb.

The same goes, when I have a flash drive connected. Is there a way around this without having to connect and disconnect each time?

Answer (score 8):

Your bios settings probably are selecting the external HDDs as primary, press F2, f10, or the del key as your computers boots and edit the default hard drive, that should fix your issue

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could press <kbd>ESC</kbd> (or a similar key, probably <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F10</kbd>) to access the boot menu and selecting the internal hard drive to boot from. You would have to do this every time you boot with an external drive connected, though.

Answer (score 0):

BIOS settings is a possible.....how long do you let it try to boot?  It could be running checkdisk on the external drive.  If it's a TB drive with some errors that can take a while.  I had this problem with a server once, but it was a peculiarity with the motherboard not a bios setting.

Comment: But letting the checkdisk run would stop it coming up the next time you booted, the issue seems to be that its trying to boot from the external HDD.

Comment: yes, but she says "won't boot" which makes me think she is being impatient with chkdsk if it is the case

Answer (score 0):

For windows 10, I had to go into BIOS and in `boot` menu, disabled `USB Boot Support', that fixed it. I had the Seagate hard drive.

Note, my boot order was already right and first choice of internal hdd, still it will try to load from the USB drive it seems.